# Is there any equivalent for TempDir() but for the /run directory?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, go, cross-platform

The `/run` directory on Linux provides [run-time data](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s15.html) such as socket information/etc. It is useful to write this information to a file for other processes to read.

In Go, there is the system independent [`TempDir()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#TempDir) which returns the default directory to use for temporary files.

Is there such a filesystem independent method for `/run`? If not, is there a standard (formal or otherwise) for writing this information in a cross platform friendly way (e.g. a single Go function that returned the correct location on MacOS, Windows & Linux)?